# create combination of delimited strings by group in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe.
in which i have a column against each ID which is delimited by some delimiter.

I want to create some combination of those delimited strings by group.

The raw data is like below image.

```
ID  paths
1   [ test1 ]--[ test2 ]--[ test3 ]--[ test4 ]--[ test5 ]--[ test6 ]--[ tets7 ]
2   [ test1 ]--[ test2 ]--[ test3 ]--[ test4 ]
```

I want the output which will look like this.

```
ID  combination
1   [ test1 ]--[ test2 ]
1   [ test2 ]--[ test3 ]
1   [ test3 ]--[ test4 ]
1   [ test4 ]--[ test5 ]
1   [ test5 ]--[ test6 ]
1   [ test6 ]--[ tets7 ]
2   [ test1 ]--[ test2 ]
2   [ test2 ]--[ test3 ]
2   [ test3 ]--[ test4 ]
```

Can anyone help.

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.pairwise`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.pairwise) to generate the pairs, then [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) into new rows.

*NB. `pairwise` requires python ≥ 3.10, for older versions, [there is a recipe for it in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.pairwise)*

```
from itertools import pairwise

(df.assign(paths=[list(map('--'.join, pairwise(s.split('--'))))
                  for s in df['paths']])
   .explode('paths')
)
```

output:

```
   ID                 paths
0   1  [ test1 ]--[ test2 ]
0   1  [ test2 ]--[ test3 ]
0   1  [ test3 ]--[ test4 ]
0   1  [ test4 ]--[ test5 ]
0   1  [ test5 ]--[ test6 ]
0   1  [ test6 ]--[ tets7 ]
1   2  [ test1 ]--[ test2 ]
1   2  [ test2 ]--[ test3 ]
1   2  [ test3 ]--[ test4 ]
```

###### alternative using [`groupby`+`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html):

```
(df.assign(paths=df['paths'].str.split('--'))
   .explode('paths')
   .assign(paths=lambda d: d['paths'].groupby(d['ID']).shift()+'--'+d['paths'])
   .dropna(subset=['paths'])
)
```

Comment: @RohitM check the itertools documentation. I explicitly wrote it in the answer, if you have python < 3.10 you need to import `itertools.tee` and define the pairwise function as described in the docs. The first solution should be a bit faster ;)